# when i use pointer, input:5 output:0x29987 but when i dont use pointer i take error at 18. line

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, bubble-sort, function-definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class T> void sortArray(T items, int count) {
  T t;
  for (int a = 1; a < 5; a++) {
    for (int b = count - 1; b >= a; b--) {
      if (items[b - 1] > items[b]) {
        t = items[b - 1];
        items[b - 1] = items[b];
        items[b] = t;
      }
    }
  }
}
template <class T> void printArray(T items, int count) {
  T array[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
}
int main() {
  int b[5];
  double d[5];
  char c[5];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    cin >> b[i];
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    cin >> d[i];
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    cin >> c[i];
    i++;
  }
  sortArray(b, 5);
  sortArray(d, 5);
  sortArray(c, 5);
  printArray(b, 5);
  printArray(d, 5);
  printArray(c, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "error at 18. line". Where's line 18?

Comment: What "error"? This question is lacking any real detail or information. Pretend we're not sitting in front of your computer with you, seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: line 18 in the code you posted is `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {` which one is it in the real code?

Answer (score 1):

For starters even this function

```
template <class T> void printArray(T items, int count) {
  T array[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

does not  make sense. There is declared an uninitialized local array `array` that is outputted in a loop.

The function can be defined the following way

```
template <class T> 
std::ostream & printArray( const T *items, size_t n, std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        os << items[i] << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}
```

In calls of the template function `sortArray` like this

```
sortArray(b, 5);
```

the template type parameter is deduced to the type `int *`. So this declaration

```
T t;
```

is equivalent to

```
int *t;
```

that does not make sense.

Also within the function you are using a magic number `5`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the functions can be defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class T> 
void sortArray( T *items, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t last; !( n < 2 ) ; n = last ) 
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ ) 
        {
            if ( items[i] < items[i-1] )
            {
                std::swap( items[i-1], items[i] );
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T> 
std::ostream & printArray( const T *items, size_t n, std::ostream &os = std::cout ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        os << items[i] << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printArray( a, N ) << '\n';

    sortArray( a, N );  

    printArray( a, N ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```